# Does LSApplicationWorkspace not work on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, ios11

I have an app in private which need to scan all applications and schemes and get it by using private API `LSApplicationWorkspace defaultWorkspace` with others functional method, such as `privateURLSchemes` `allInstalledApplications`. This app works good and I can get all I need from the private API before iOS 11, but in this version I only got some warning and an empty array. It seems Apple limits private API that developer can't use in private in iOS 11.

So my question is what alternative ways can achieve my need in iOS 11?

Comment: I‘m also very interested how we can proceed. We need the info   from „allInstalledApplications“ in our own company-wide enterprise AppStore (to check, which apps are already installed). Have you already filed a radar to Apple about this?

Comment: No, I haven't. but thank you for your reminder.

Comment: I filed a radar #33150439 on this. Feel free to mention this radar # in your radar.

Comment: I had also filed a radar for this topic (#33062089). Feel free to duplicate. Unfortunately it still didn’t work in beta 3.

Comment: Apple has closed my radar with the comment „This issue behaves as intended.“ :(

Comment: My radar was closed too. :(

Comment: Ok, so we need another solution for this. :/ Any ideas?

Comment: http://m.blog.csdn.net/Yj_sail/article/details/78186723 here a possible solution. It is in chinese, so i trust Google Translate :) I've no iOS 11 device, so i can't try. It might be helpful

Comment: It's a private API for checking whether an app is installed by using bundle id. It worked, amazing.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: This method does not work on iOS 12 - entitlement required

There is a way to find if a specific application is installed, its not a list of all apps like `allInstalledApplications` returned but its useful to query for a specific bundle id

Here is an example, the method receives bundle id and return true if it's installed on the device:

```
- (BOOL)checkIfAppInstalled: (NSString*)bundleID {
    dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileContainerManager.framework/MobileContainerManager",RTLD_NOW);
    Class MBAppManager = NSClassFromString(@"MCMAppDataContainer");
    NSError  * error ;
    id contentApp = [MBAppManager performSelector:@selector(containerWithIdentifier:error:) withObject:bundleID withObject:error];
    return contentApp != nil;
}
```

Comment: Search the API... (finding a needle in haystack)

Answer (score 1):

Private API is just that—private API. Using it is completely unsupported, and as such, you cannot rely on a private API continuing to work in future versions of the OS.

In addition, I would be highly surprised if an app that used private API were able to get into the App Store, since it's one of the things Apple's reviewers scan for.

Answer (score 0):

In enterprise you can use Apple Mobile Device Management (MDM) Protocol ManagedApplicationList commands to get the status of managed applications

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](http://blog.csdn.net/Yj_sail/article/details/78186723). From the comment of @ovo under the original question, it seems works.

Using `MobileContainerManager.framework` it's possible to check if an app is installed by using bundle id.

```
//If the device is iOS11
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 11.0) {
        NSBundle *container = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileContainerManager.framework"];
        if ([container load]) {
            Class appContainer = NSClassFromString(@"MCMAppContainer");

            id test = [appContainer performSelector:@selector(containerWithIdentifier:error:) withObject:bundleId withObject:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@",test);
            if (test) {
                return YES;
            } else {
                return NO;
            }
        }
        return NO;

    } else {
           //Usual way
    }
```

Comment: Tested on iOS 11. This code doesn't work. containerWithIdentifier returns nil for everything.

Comment: Tested right now. It works. Also @inspector_60 answer works in this way.

Answer (score -1):

i got same Apple Reject.

Apple Says

> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> LSApplicationWorkspace
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because
>   it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
>
> Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of
>   this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.

**Solutions**

To find out which library or code is causing this problem use the below code snipped.

1-) Open the terminal in macbook (cmd+ space) and than write terminal

2-) change the project directory with the below code

```
cd  /Users/emreg/Documents/{your project url}
```

3-) To search appropriate word

```
grep -r LSApplicationWorkspace .
grep -r allApplications .
```

in my case, Blesh SDK has included LSApplicationWorkspace and allApplications keyword which is not permitted by Apple. When i upteded SDK, my problem is solved.

i hope, this answer will help someone.