# LSApplicationWorkspace Broken in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

LSApplicationWorkspace is a private API in iOS that allows you to see what apps are installed on a device. Apple does not allow you to use private API's when you submit to the App Store, but I need this solution for an enterprise app.

LSApplicationWorkspace is broken in iOS 11. The headers are still there, but the class no longer returns a list of products.

Has anyone found a solution for getting LSApplicationWorkspace to work in iOS 11?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793215/does-lsapplicationworkspace-not-work-on-ios-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work without jailbreak. Apple added another rule to the sandbox that limits use of `LSApplicationWorkspace`. You can see that in the syslog. Probably needs special entitlement like pretty much every other private API.